# Where is the link to the per-site meta in the new top bar?

Tags: support, top-bar

I'm trying to find the link to my site's meta site on the new top bar and I can't find it. In fact I can't find it anywhere on the page.

For example: electronics.meta.stackexchange.com.

Perhaps I'm just not very perceptive, or possibly this is an opportunity to improve the new design.

Comment: In the hamburger menu / site switcher at the right

Comment: The tooltip hasn't changed. :)

Comment: @AdamLear, I wasn't using the tooltip before, because I already knew where to find the link to the meta site. You only notice a UI problem like that when you have to look at it as if you are a new user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have found it, but here's a screenshot for people who are still confused:

[image: dropdown]

It is located **in the hamburger dropdown on the top right**, next to the help icon. It's the new site switcher, with a link to meta, chat, and the main site, plus all other SE sites.

The old site switcher now displays a popup linking to https://stackexchange.com.

Comment: I am here because every time I click on the logo Stack Exchange I find myself on the main page, then I click on the word meta (right-hand side) and it brings me here, each and every bloody time. I want my old menu on the left side. I want to see a drop menu when I click on StackExchange not be automatically taken to the main page. I'm 51, I'm getting old and cranky,  you can't expect me to learn new tricks. Who's in charge around here. I demand to see the manager (kidding, sorta but not very)

Comment: Considering the updates to the top bar, this seems to need some new screenshots. ;)

Answer (score 6):

The icon at the extreme right, that looks like the StackExchange logo (and is often called the 'hamburger') links to your communities, and for the current community also links to the community's meta:

[image: Hamburger Menu, clicked on - StackOverflow example]