# Asking a question pertaining to another SE site that doesn't have meta

Tags: support, per-site-meta

There is a question that I would like to ask pertaining to another SE site (mechanics namely, and a burninate request in particular), but I have been unable to find a meta site for this (like meta.se or meta.so).

So, would asking a question (that would be off-topic for the primary site in question), on meta.se (here) be appropriate?

If not, where would be good for them to go?

Comment: I think all sites have a meta, there's is here: https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Every site has respective meta. Similarly, mechanics also has one [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair meta](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No idea how I missed that! Thanks! :)

Comment: You can find a link in the hamburger menu at the top right: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301907/158100

Comment: @rene and direct link in footer, named "feedback".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Almost)* every site has its own 'child Meta'; for Mechanics it's https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/. The child meta is also mentioned (and sort of linked to) in the Help Center article [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

You can reach Meta via the hamburger menu (as mentioned by @rene):
[image]
or via the Feedback link in the footer (as mentioned by @ShadowWizard):
[image]

*<sub>: as Nathan Tuggy mentions, some exceptional sites like Meta Stack Exchange itself and [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) are more or less their own Metas.</sub>