# Too many hamburgers and not enough space for icons

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design

This is how the new responsive design looks on a narrow screen when you have a lot of stuff going on in the top bar:

[image]

This is how it looks when you narrow the screen a bit:

[image]

The help and the review icons are gone now. Which is the expected behaviour for a responsive design, and as I'm familiar with this concept, I'd simply look into the hamburger menu that contains the overflow menu items.

There are several issues with this in the new SE design. There isn't a single hamburger menu here, **there are three of them** (credit goes to Sklivvz for [noticing this first](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4285/5) and pointing me towards this issue).

Well, two of them look a bit like the SE logo, but they're still very similar in design to a hamburger menu, and ones of them actually works similar to one. And the other issue is that **not a single one of those three hamburger menus actually contains the overflowing top bar items**. As far as I can tell, the icons that are hidden due to a lack of space simply disappear, there is no way to reach them in this case.

How is a new user supposed to understand how this works? Any why are the overflow items not present in any of the hamburger menus, there are certainly enough of them?

Comment: For new users (who won't have review, much less the mod menu), help disappears at a width of 305 pixels (based off "inspect" on Chrome). However, for people with access to reviews, help disappears at a width of 340, and it's missing on my tiny phone screen.

Comment: @Laurel the part about new users is targeted towards the presence of three icons that look like hamburger menus, not the behaviour of overflowing icons. I didn't make that clear, but I really doubt any new user would understand my first screenshot.

Comment: If you're looking for the "new user experience" you might want to take your screenshots on a site where you're not a mod. ;) You have two extra icons just by that alone. Also, the "help" link is in the site switcher (the one on the right).

Comment: @Catija Maybe I should have split this post, but there are two major issues. One is that there are three hamburger-like icons, two of which are menus, and none of which behave entirely like a typical hamburger menu. The other issue is that icons that are overflowing are not put into any of the hamburger menus, like you'd usually do. The former of these issues affects new users, the latter mostly doesn't

Comment: Related: [Three hamburgers but still no link to meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315895/three-hamburgers-but-still-no-direct-link-to-meta)

Comment: "as I'm familiar with this concept, I'd simply look into the hamburger menu that contains the overflow menu items." I just tested it, and I can't find those items once they're hidden from the bar :/