# Provide an easier way to find the meta of each Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, navigation

I could not find the meta of Web Applications. It should have been easier to find (I did not find it actually, I just added "meta" to the URL).

Comment: Many possible ways to get Meta. One easiest way -> [Please find the "?" icon in the top bar then Meta link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6tDZ.png) in the Web Apps.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being negatively received. We get lots of site-specific questions on this site, from users who are completely unaware of the existence of per-site metas. In most cases, after I advise them of the way to access the per-site meta (through the site switcher), they then apologize and move on their way.

Comment: @Arulkumar Not a duplicate. That is a support question; this is an (albeit weak) feature request.

Comment: On stack, for each problem to solve, you get 3 guys downvoting, because why not, 3 guys downvoting because they find the answer too obvious (but too hard to write it down), 3 to 4 guys marking it as duplicated or saying it belong somewhere else. Sometime, someone try to solve the problem. Stack reflects very much humanity.

Comment: Closely related: [Three “hamburgers” but still no direct link to meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315895/three-hamburgers-but-still-no-direct-link-to-meta)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog For once, I agree about your bewilderment! It's also worth mentioning that downvoters don't lose rep for downvoting questions.

Comment: *On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.* (from the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)). I didn't downvote but I can imagine people think three links on every page is enough, even though you have to open a menu or scroll to the bottom to see them.

Comment: @Glorfindel said "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement ".  So why do the vote buttons still say the choice is based on research etc.?

Comment: Because the tooltips are the same on all sites. Also, one could argue that a feature request one disagrees with isn't really useful. But that's a separate [discussion] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old days it was in the top bar.

It's a simple matter of clicking on the SE logo while on any site, and pick the meta site from the drop down menu:

[image]

Comment: thats indeed where I look for it

Answer (score 1):

- You can scroll to the footer and click the 'Feedback' link (left)
- As @Arulkumar noted in the comments, there's a link to Meta in the Help Center menu (right)

[image: footer menu]
[image]

- Some sites have Hot or Featured Meta Posts (Web Applications currently does not have them). You can reach Meta by clicking on one of those posts:

[image]

Comment: thank you but that the last place I would have look for (but still better than in "save file")